# How to resolve service names in a Docker Swarm?

Tags: http, docker, dns, swarm

I am playing around with Docker and stuff, using this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  frontend:
    image: apmimg:latest
    networks:
      - core-infra    
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure


  backend:
    image: productsapi:latest
    volumes:
      - myvol:/opt/myvol
    networks:
      - core-infra
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure


networks:
  core-infra:
    driver: overlay

volumes:
  myvol: 
    driver: local
```

And when I ssh into frontend and ping backend "***ping mysite_backend***" it does **work**.

But when I try to make a HTTP request from my Node.js code:

```
private _productUrl = "http://mysite_backend/api/products";  

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]>
{
    let url = this._productUrl;
    return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(url)
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I get a "***Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED***", even in the same host.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: You have to expose the ports of your backend service to the host machine.

Comment: Does your `productsapi:latest` is listen on port 80? Exposing port to host machine is not necessary

Comment: Yes. productsapi is listening in port 80. 
If I expose it like 8081:80 and access *http://localhost:8081/api/products* I get the response I want but it is not the environment I want to build.